Initial value problem - chemical kinetics
Given is the chemical system: $A \to B \to C$ with rate constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively $(k_1, k_2 >0)$.
At $t=0$ the concentrations are $(A_0, 0, 0)$. The rate of change in concentrations $[A]$, $[B]$, $[C]$ are given by:
$d[A]/dt = -k_1 [A]$
$d[B]/dt = k_1 [A] - k_2[B]$
$d[C]/dt = k_2 [B]$
When considering the case $k_1 = k_2 = k$, I found the eigenvalues to be $-k$ and $0$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, and $(0, 0, 1)$ (i.e. the canonical vectors)
However, this results in $[A]_t = A_0*exp(-kt)$ and $[B]_t = 0$ and $[C]_t = 0$. This makes me wonder how the concentration of A can change over time, while the concentrations of B and C don't change. Or did I make a mistake in my computations?

how did you obtain $B=0$?

I first wrote x0 as a linear combination of the eigenvectors (e1, e2, e3): x0 = c1 e1 + c2 e2 + c3 e3. Since x0 = (A0, 0, 0), I found c1 = A0 and c2 = c3 = 0. Then I wrote the general solution: x(t) = ([A], [B], [C]) = c1 exp(λ1t) e1 + c2 exp(λ2t) e2 + c3 exp (λ3t) e3 = ( A0*exp(λ1t), 0, 0)

you can solve directly the system

What exactly do you mean by 'directly solving the system'?

Yes, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Consider the system
$$\begin{cases} 
A'=-kA\\ B'=kA-kB\\C'=kB
\end{cases}$$
with the initial condition given by $(A(0),B(0),C(0))=(A_0,0,0)$.
From the first equation, you have $A(t)=A_0e^{-kt}$, now you can substitute $A$ in the second equation:
$$B'=A_0ke^{-kt}-kB $$
This is a first order linear equation:
$$(B'+kB)e^{kt}=A_0k \implies \frac{d}{dt}(Be^{kt})=A_0k\implies B(t)=A_0kte^{-kt}$$
To obtain $C$, note that $A'+B'+C'=0$, so $A+B+C=A_0$ and $C=A_0-A-B$

Thank you for your answer! Does this mean C(t) = A0 - A(t) - B(t)?

@Jack yes, since $A'+B'+C'=0$ this implies $A+B+C=\text{constant}$, but at the time $t=0$, you have $A(0)+B(0)+C(0)=A_0$, hence $C(t)=A_0-A(t)-B(t)$

Out of curiosity, why didn't my method with eigenvectors/eigenvalues work out?

@Jack It works, but probably you've made a mistake

I tried to solve det(A-λI) = 0 where A = coefficient matrix of the system, and I found that  λ1 = -k and λ2 = 0. When I compute the corresponding eigenvectors, I only find 2 eigenvectors: v1 = (0, -1, 1) and v2 = (0, 0, 1). With only two vectors, I cannot find x(t) = ([A], [B], [C]). Do you maybe see where my mistake is (in eigenvalues, or in  eigenvectors?)

@Jack $k$ has multiplicity $2$

Yes, I know because det (A-λI) = -λ(-k-λ)^2 = 0 gives λ1 = -k, λ2 = 0. However, when I solve the system (A+kI) x = 0, then I only find 1 vector: (0, -1, 1) ?

@Jack if you solve the system, you find $z=0$ so you have two vectors, you can take $e_1$ and $e_2$ for example
